# simple_pdf_viewer crashes on api level 30 [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, crash, android-11, androidpdfviewer

App crashes while trying to open pdf in flutter. I have used "simple_pdf_viewer: ^0.2.2".
I have attached the details of the crash report below :

Library link : [simple_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_pdf_viewer) .

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
```

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.get(Platform.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:296)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.java:262)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1054)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at com.liyuanhust.pdfviewer.FileLoader.(FileLoader.kt:155)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at com.liyuanhust.pdfviewer.PdfView.(PdfView.kt:30)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at com.liyuanhust.pdfviewer.PdfViewerFactory.create(PdfViewerFactory.kt:14)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:186)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:419)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:313)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.(VirtualDisplayController.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:738)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.findPlatform(Platform.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.(Platform.java:79)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7294): ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]**
I have solved this issue.

Anyone referring to this in future, change the okhttp dependency version to 3.14.7 in the simple_pdf_viewer library present in /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ , it is working fine in android 11 as well.